# When I ALTER PROCEDURE i get the error "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server.."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure works just fine if I right click and execute 
but if I right click and **modify then execute** I get this error:

> Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A transport-level error has
>   occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host.)

Furthermore, when I run the query by itself it works fine too.

I need to modify this SP so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: Perhaps something went south on the server side. Check the SQL Server error log for unexpected messages, such as a mini dump.

Comment: i have same problem, I disabled the Symantec Network Threat Protection on both, my machine as well as the SQL Server machine.. and it now runs fine!!

Comment: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO59111.html

Comment: @HasanFathi where do I find Symantec Network Threat Protection on my machine/SQL server?

Comment: Also verify you're not trying to access a very new version of SQL Server with a very old version of Management Studio. While for the most part things are compatible, every so often they're not. (The reverse, accessing an old server with a new Management Studio, is much more reliable.)

Comment: please visit my link in comment

Comment: @HasanFathi The link doesn't explain where to go in order to login/disable

Comment: @Sorath which `version`  of SQL you are using ?

Comment: @Sorath use this: https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/permanently-disable-network-threat-protection-stand-alone-server

Comment: @HasanFathi   When I do SELECT @@VERSION it says MS SQL Server 2008 but when I check in control panel I also see a bunch of MS SQL Server 2012 installed

Comment: use this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47090/how-to-make-sql-server-management-studio-use-latest-version-of-sql-server